# Jquery Mobile Collapsible Set refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-collapsible, jquery-mobile-ajax

I have an accordion in jquery mobile that is being populated through json data. In order to keep the styling, I call `$( ".folders" ).collapsibleset.( "refresh" );` after all the data has been appended and it works, but only for the main folders. In my code I have made subfolders and those do not receive the styling changes. Here is my folder code

```html
<div class="folders" data-role="collapsible-set" data-corners="false"  data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
   <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Main Folder</h3>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Sub Folder</h3>
            <p>
                Subtext
            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Folder</h3>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
             <h3>Folder</h3>
             <p>Text</p>
        </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$( ".folders" ).collapsibleset.().trigger('create')`.

Comment: i get this error. SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '(' instead

Comment: nevermind, i reposted the code and it works. thank you!

Comment: There's an extra dot after collapsibleset, my bad.